# What is the best way to flush user session data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

PHP / CodeIgniter

From what I can see in the CI manual, to flush user data from the session, one creates an array with the values and calls `$this->session->unset_userdata('$array')`

Two questions actually:

1. Is there not a more elegant way to "flush everything"?
2. Is there a risk of flushing core critical session information like session id, user agent, etc?

{CLARIFICATION] Not wanting to terminate the session... just rather do some housekeeping.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the session...depending on what possibilities you want your user to have afterwords

```
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Destroying a Session

To clear the current session:

$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

or by unsetting specific variables

```
This function can also be passed an associative array of items to unset.

$array_items = array('username' => '', 'email' => '');

$this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
```

I do not see a point to do housekeeping but rather just to update the session when needed is all...

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of housekeeping. I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can try:

```
session_destroy();
```

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of housekeeping. I'll update the question